# UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification not sending notification for brightness of 0.0

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, brightness, screen-brightness, uiscreen

Normally registering for `UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification` provides notifications when the user finishes sliding the brightness slider in control center.
It appears there is a bug that prevents notifications from being sent when the brightness is set to `0.0`. Basically the range of values which produce notifications are (0.0, 1.0]

**Am I missing something here?**

Testing is as simple as:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserverForName:UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification
                    object:nil
                     queue:nil
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
{
    NSLog(@"Brightness changed: %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]);
}];
```

Comment: I tested it on a device and apparently you're right. It only works when I set brightness to 1.0, then go all the way to 0.0. So from 1.0 -> 0.0 it logs 0.0. But from anything else -> 0.0 it doesn't log anything.

Comment: I think you should report it on https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Thank you for confirming @Armin! I found [a duplicate via OpenRadar](http://blackpixel.com/blog/2012/02/radar-or-gtfo.html) and filed my own actual Radar (#19686330). Please feel free to help file a duplicate!
Thanks again for proving I'm not crazy :)

Comment: hahaha no worries! I tested on an iPhone 4S btw. Will do.